# Verifying many properties cleanly [separately outside of single verify call] of an argument passed to Mock?

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

```
saveThemeAS.Verify(service => service.Execute(FakeUserID, It.Is<LayoutENT.Theme>(savedTheme => 
            savedTheme != null
            && savedTheme.Name == FakeCopiedThemeName
            && savedTheme.ThemeID == 0
            && savedTheme.WidgetSkins.Any(skin => skin.Name == FakeWidgetSkinName && skin.WidgetSkinID == 0)
            && savedTheme.SiteStyles.Any(style => style.SiteStyleID == FakeStyleID && style.SiteStyleID == 0)
            )));
```

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed:

The basic problem here is I just get a failure, but I don't know *specifically* what failed/ what was not set appropriately as it could be any one of the 5 conditions above.

I would like to check each condition above seperately. Is there a slick way to do this with Moq without creating multiple tests? I thought it would be nice to be able to capture the argument passed to the mock and then test against that, but I haven't been able to find an elegant way to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think my approach to this problem would be to use a callback in the mock setup, such that the callback saves a copy of the savedTheme object that was passed to it. Then I'd perform asserts later in my unit test. This preserves the triple-A (Arrange, Act, Assert) pattern and seems cleaner than putting the assert logic into the mock setup. So for example:

```
protected static LayoutENT.Theme savedTheme;
// Arrange
themeParam = null;
saveThemeAS.Setup(service => service.Execute(FakeUserID, It.Is<LayoutENT.Theme>)
    .Callback<layoutENT.Theme>(p =>  savedTheme = p);

// Act
// Calls the subject under test

// Assert
Assert.IsNotNull(savedTheme); 
Assert.AreEqual(FakeCopiedThemeName, savedTheme.Name); 
Assert.AreEqual(0, savedTheme.ThemeID)
```

etc...

Answer (score 5):

In essence, what you are asking for is for your inner lambda to perform a series of assertions rather than simply evaluate to a boolean value.

So let's do exactly that :)

```
saveThemeAS.Verify(service => service.Execute(FakeUserID, It.Is<LayoutENT.Theme>(savedTheme => 
   {
      Assert.IsNotNull(savedTheme);
      Assert.AreEqual(FakeCopiedThemeName, savedTheme.Name);
      Assert.AreEqual(0, savedTheme.ThemeID)

      etc...

      return true;     
   }
)));
```

You could move the assertions to a separate method for clearity.

If you want to get rid of the "return true;" you could write a wrapper for Action<T> that returns a Func<T,bool> that always returns true. That way you could write something along the lines of:

```
saveThemeAS.Verify(service => service.Execute(FakeUserID, It.Is<LayoutENT.Theme>(ReturnsTrue(CheckTheme))))
```